# SMIL adaptive streaming in Videojs

Tags: video.js, wowza, smil, adaptive-bitrate, wowza-transcoder

What is required to use SMIL file to utilize adaptive streaming in a videojs player.  I have created the SMIL file in my wowza application and it is creating my 4 separate streams and making them available.  However I cannot get my webpage, that uses videojs, to correctly play the SMIL file.  Hints on that coding or where to go to find the correct documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many implementations of SMIL players. I'm sure I've seen wowza URLs that suggest it will output the SMIL as other formats, something like whatever.smil/manifest.m3u8. That's HLS which could be played on mobile and Safari natively and with [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I've been struggling with this recently, so I want to share my experience in case anyone is interested. My scenario is very similar: **want to deliver adaptive bitrate streaming from Wowza to clients using videojs.**

There is a [master link](https://www.wowza.com/docs/How-to-set-up-and-run-Wowza-Transcoder-for-live-streaming) that explains how to setup and run Wowza Transcoder for live streaming, and how to set up your Adaptive Bitrate Streams using an SMIL file. Following the video in there you can achieve to have a stream that uses ABS, but the SMIL file is attached to the stream name, so it is not a solution if you have streams that come to Wowza from another Media Server origin and that need to be transcoded before being served to the clients. In the article there are a few key things mentioned (like the Stream Name Groups), but somehow things doesn't seem pretty clear, at least to me. So here is some clarification from what I understood from all articles I read and what I did to achieve ABS:

- You can achieve ABS in Wowza either with SMIL files or with Stream Name Groups (NGRP). NGRP refres to a block of streams that is defined in the Transcoder template that can be played back using multi-bitrate streaming (dynamically) (<- this is what I used). And SMIL files are used to create a "static" list of streams for multi-bitrate VOD streaming. If you are using [Wowza Origin-Edge Delivery](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-a-live-stream-repeater) you'll need the .smil file, because NGRP do not get forwarded to the edge. (Source for all this information: [here](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-create-and-play-smil-files-with-streams-created-by-wowza-transcoder)).
- In case you need the SMIL file, you probably need to generate a new one for every stream, and probably you want to do that in an automated way, so best way would be through an HTTP request (in the link above it is explained how to achieve this).
- In case you can live with NGRP, things are a bit easier:

  1. You need to **enable Wowza Transcoder** (this is pretty easy and steps are in the video I mention above).
  2. You should **create your own Transcoder Template with the different stream presets you want to deliver**, as an example you can check the default ones that are already there. The more presets you add, the more work Wowza will need to do whenever a stream comes, since it will need to generate a new stream for every preset that you have defined.
  3. Now is when we **generate the NGRPs**. In your Transcoder Template, you can generate as many NGRPs as you want (to clarify: these are like groups of streams, that you will be able to set in your clients video player. **Each NGRP contains the streams that the video will be able to use when doing the adaptive bitrate streaming**). For instance, these are the default NGRPs:

[image]

If you play the ngrp "_mobile" in the clients video player, the ABS algorithm in the player will be able to adapt itself to play either the 240p or the 160p streams based on the client capabilities.

So imagine you have these two NGRP. **In order to play them in videoJS, you will need to set the source to**:

```
http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/<name-of-your-application>/ngrp:myStream_all/playlist.m3u8
```

or

```
http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/<name-of-your-application>/ngrp:myStream_mobile/playlist.m3u8
```

... based on how many options you want to provide to the client player to use for the ABS. (For instance: if your targets are old mobile devices, you probably just want to offer a couple of low bitrate streams).
(This would be in case you're delivering an HLS stream. If other format, the extension would change, for instance if you are delivering a DASH stream you would have "*/manifest.mpd*" instead of "*playlist.m3u8*").

That is all, **there is also a very helpful link in video.js documentation explaining how it does the bitrate switching: [here](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/blob/master/docs/bitrate-switching.md).**

I hope it helps someone! At least clarifying things! :)